# How to create a container in Rancher using API

Tags: docker, rancher

I am trying to create a container running on a specific host in Rancher.

But i only get the error :

```
2017-10-05 08:11:25,129 ERROR [:] [] [] [] [utorService-545] [.e.s.i.ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl] Unknown exception running process [instance.create:1470844] on [27784] io.cattle.platform.util.exception.ExecutionException: Failed to find network for networkMode bridge
at io.cattle.platform.docker.process.instance.DockerInstancePreCreate.handle(DockerInstancePreCreate.java:65) ~[cattle-docker-compute-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.runHandler(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:470) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl$4.execute(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:421) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl$4.execute(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:415) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.idempotent.Idempotent.execute(Idempotent.java:42) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.runHandlers(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:415) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.runLogic(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:514) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.runWithProcessLock(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:345) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl$2.doWithLockNoResult(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:245) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.LockCallbackNoReturn.doWithLock(LockCallbackNoReturn.java:7) ~[cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.LockCallbackNoReturn.doWithLock(LockCallbackNoReturn.java:3) ~[cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl$3.doWithLock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:40) ~[cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.LockManagerImpl.doLock(LockManagerImpl.java:33) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl.lock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:13) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl.lock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:37) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.acquireLockAndRun(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:242) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.runDelegateLoop(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:184) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.executeWithProcessInstanceLock(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:157) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl$1.doWithLock(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:116) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl$1.doWithLock(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:113) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl$3.doWithLock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:40) ~[cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.LockManagerImpl.doLock(LockManagerImpl.java:33) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl.lock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:13) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl.lock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:37) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.process.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.execute(DefaultProcessInstanceImpl.java:113) ~[cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.server.impl.ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl.processExecuteWithLock(ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl.java:136) [cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.server.impl.ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl$1.doWithLock(ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl.java:123) [cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.server.impl.ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl$1.doWithLock(ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl.java:120) [cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl$4.doWithLock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:50) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.LockManagerImpl.doLock(LockManagerImpl.java:33) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl.tryLock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:25) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.lock.impl.AbstractLockManagerImpl.tryLock(AbstractLockManagerImpl.java:47) [cattle-framework-lock-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.server.impl.ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl.execute(ProcessInstanceDispatcherImpl.java:120) [cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at io.cattle.platform.engine.server.ProcessInstanceReference.doRun(ProcessInstanceReference.java:59) [cattle-framework-engine-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.apache.cloudstack.managed.context.NoExceptionRunnable.runInContext(NoExceptionRunnable.java:15) [cattle-framework-managed-context-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.apache.cloudstack.managed.context.ManagedContextRunnable$1.run(ManagedContextRunnable.java:49) [cattle-framework-managed-context-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.apache.cloudstack.managed.context.impl.DefaultManagedContext$1.call(DefaultManagedContext.java:55) [cattle-framework-managed-context-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.apache.cloudstack.managed.context.impl.DefaultManagedContext.callWithContext(DefaultManagedContext.java:108) [cattle-framework-managed-context-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.apache.cloudstack.managed.context.impl.DefaultManagedContext.runWithContext(DefaultManagedContext.java:52) [cattle-framework-managed-context-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.apache.cloudstack.managed.context.ManagedContextRunnable.run(ManagedContextRunnable.java:46) [cattle-framework-managed-context-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
```

I am using the web api with the following POST data:

```
HTTP/1.1 POST /v2-beta/launchconfigs
Host: test1.iot.iavtech.net
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 708

{

"build": null,
"capAdd": [ ],
"capDrop": [ ],
"command": [ ],
"dataVolumes": [ ],
"dataVolumesFrom": [ ],
"devices": [ ],
"dns": [ ],
"dnsOpt": [ ],
"dnsSearch": [ ],
"entryPoint": [ ],
"expose": [ ],
"extraHosts": [ ],
"groupAdd": [ ],
"healthCheck": null,
"healthCmd": [ ],
"imageUuid": "docker:ubuntu:14.04.3",
"instanceTriggeredStop": "stop",
"labels": {
    "io.rancher.container.name": "UTest",
    "io.rancher.container.pull_image": "always"
},
"logConfig": null,
"netAlias": [ ],
"networkIds": [ ],
"networkMode": "bridge",
"ports": [ ],
"privileged": false,
"publishAllPorts": false,
"readOnly": false,
"requestedHostId": "1h6",
"runInit": false,
"secrets": [ ],
"securityOpt": [ ],
"startOnCreate": true,
"stdinOpen": false,
"tty": false,
"ulimits": [ ],
"dataVolumesFromLaunchConfigs": [ ],
"disks": [ ]
}
```

I can create the container using the normal webinterface, but not with the API. The Rancher Documentation isnt very helpful, cause it is not explaining which parameters are needed.

Comment: Have you created an API user?

Comment: @Sergiu yes, Created API Key for my admin Account. its also not working if i login with my admin account and try to use the web API directly